# Is there an analytic approximation to this integral

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation

The following integral does not have an analytical form.. however, would it be possible to find an analytical approximation?

$$\int_b^c e^{-a\sqrt{x}} e^{-a \sqrt{x-b}} dx $$

with $c > b$ and $a>0$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure you mean elementary, not analytic.

Comment: I f $c$ is small, series expansion could be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following analysis is valid for $b>0$.

By the substitution $x=b\cosh^2 y$, your integral becomes
$$\int^{r}_0e^{-a\sqrt b e^y}\sinh 2y dy$$
where $r=\cosh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac cb}$.

Furthermore, substitute $u=e^y$, yielding
$$b^2\left(\int^{e^r}_1ue^{-a\sqrt b u}du +\int^{e^r}_1 u^{-3}e^{-a\sqrt bu}du\right)$$

The first term can be written in closed form, and the second can be expressed in terms of incomplete gamma function.

$$\int^{e^r}_1ue^{-a\sqrt b u}du =\frac{-(a\sqrt be^r+1)e^{-a\sqrt be^r}+(a\sqrt b+1)e^{-a\sqrt b}}{a^2b}$$

$$\int^{e^r}_1 u^{-3}e^{-a\sqrt bu}du=a^2b\cdot[\Gamma(-2,a\sqrt b )-\Gamma(-2,a\sqrt b e^r)]$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) gives some asymptotic approximations under the section ‘asymptotic behavior’.

Comment: Thanks @Szeto! Really nice solution! I didn't think it was solvable! I can now work from there! :)

Comment: @Jordi Sorry I made a mistake when evaluating the first integral. I have corrected it now.